# Как EXE-шнику удалить самого себя?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно написать программу которая после исполнения удалит сама себя.
Как можно это сделать?
Я написал небольшой код.

Но стоит мне его скомпилить в EXE-шник и он не работает.

Код:

```
import os
a = __file__
a1 = []
for i in a:
    a1.append(i)

del a1[-2::]
a = ''
for i in a1:
    a += str(i)

a += 'exe'
del a1

os.remove(a)
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
    File "test.py" line 15, in (module)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError2] Не удается найти указанный файл: 'test.exe'
[2204] Failed to execute script test
```

Comment: что-то мне кажется, что по простому нет. Но можно наверное создать задание на удаление экзешника.

Comment: Попробуйте `import os
    os.system(f'rm {__file__}')`

Comment: Нет, это не сработает. Если вы выведете в консоль `__file__` (`print(__file__)`), скомпилируете в exe, запустите, то в консоль будет выведено имя файла с расширением "py". Более того, если вы измените имя exe файла, то результатом останется имя того файла, который вы изначально компилировали. То есть вы не знаете имя исполняемого exe файла, из чего следует, что `os.remove()` у вас не получится использовать.

Comment: Дело в том что когда я запускаю этот скрипт(test.py) в одной директории с test.exe то exe-шник удалиться

Comment: Понятное дело, вы же меняете .py на .exe в скрипте О_о

Comment: Только делаете вы это очень странно.... Вы смотрели, что у вас лежит в переменной `a` на момент вызова `os.remove(a)`?

Comment: Чтобы получить имя файла в скомпилированной программе нужно использовать sys.argv[0] # "D:\DIR\\DIR\\program.exe"

Comment: Разве в Windows можно удалить занятый чем-то файл (а запущенный файл таким является)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо за участие в моем вопросе
Я понял что окна не могут удалить файл который делает что-то
Задача была решена посредством создания батника и его запуска из самой программы

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

name = sys.argv[0]

print(name)

# запустив скрипт ты получишь следующее:
# E:\Python\exampeles\test.py
# запустив скомпилированную прогу ты получишь:
# E:\Python\exampeles\test.exe
# Даже когда ты потом ее переименуешь ты получишь путь к ней и ее имя
```

Comment: Вот только вы кое что забыли, при запуске из консоли, там не будет пути к файлу.

Comment: Почему?                                                                                                                                        Ввожу в консоль -> python E:\Python\exampeles\t.py
Вывод -> E:\Python\exampeles\t.py

Ввожу в консоль ->  E:\Python\exampeles\t.py
Вывод -> E:\Python\exampeles\t.py

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте указать полный путь к файлу и заменить расширение:

```
import os
a = __file__
script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
fulladdress = script_dir + "\\" + a
os.remove(fulladdress.replace(".py",".exe"))
```

Скорее всего Вы столнетесь с ошибкой `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'test.exe'`, но это уже будет другой вопрос

Comment: После компиляции в exe переменная __file__ заменится на имя скрипта, и вдруг, вы переименуете программу, всему хана...